# Filter pcap by subsecond detail?

Tags: wireshark, filter, pcap

I'm trying to export a subset of a **pcap** file given a start and an end message, this start and end message identification is currently done using **ngrep** on the raw data(because we have no dissector for the specific protocol)

Ideally I would like to get the frame # in the pcap file of the identified start and end message and filter using it.
Unfortunately **ngrep** is not able to display a frame # (as in the first column if I look in wireshark) so the only "unique" identifier I can think of is the time stamp.

Next I'm trying to filter the original pcap file by time stamp range but run into problems with **editcap** and **tshark** not supporting sub second time stamp format as input, giving me a lot of superfluous data.

Suggestions on how to handle this in a good way? Open to alternative tools and way of attacking the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Decided to add an additional step into the pipeline in order to solve the problem, solution now looks like this:

capture -> ngrep to identify start and end fram + grab their timestamp -> tshark with time stamp range + grab frame #'s from output -> editcap to create a new pcap subset file given start frame # and end frame # from previous step.